# Debugging an Azure Function running in a Docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker-compose, azure-functions

I'd like to attach to the container and step through the code.

Can I do this with a 'Compose Up' from 'docker-compose.debug' ?
Does this start the 'func: host start'  - required for the functions runtime?

Please review my docker-compose.debug below.
Thank you.

docker-compose.debug.yaml as follows:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  nfunc:
    image: nfunc
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: ["sh", "-c", "pip install debugpy -t /tmp && python /tmp/debugpy --wait-for-client --listen 0.0.0.0:5678 mytrigger\__init__.py "]
    ports:
      - 5678:5678
```

Debugging works but not with the container, which should output a simple log message every minute.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I believe you'll have to do the profiling. You will have to follow these:

1. If its not a blessed image, then first you would have to install SSH
   if you want to get into the container.
2. Then you will have to make
   use of tools such as cProfile or other related python modules to
   profile the code.

Here is a documentation for windows application. You might want to take a look : https://azureossd.github.io/2017/09/01/profile-python-applications-in-azure-app-services/index.html

This issue has been tracked : https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker/issues/17